# I can't receive email send from my server

Tags: php, windows, apache, email, sendmail.exe

I use apache, php, and sendmail.exe on my Windows.
I download sendmail.exe and configure it like this:

```
        ; configuration for fake sendmail

    ; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
    ; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

    [sendmail]

    ; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
    ; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
    ; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
    ; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
    ; application.

    smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

    ; smtp port (normally 25)

    smtp_port=587

    ; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
    ; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
    ; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

    default_domain=domain.com

    ; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
    ; uncomment to enable logging

    error_logfile=error.log

    ; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
    ; uncomment to enable debugging

    ;debug_logfile=debug.log

    ; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

    auth_username=admin@whilgeek.com
    auth_password=19910610

    ; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
    ; following three lines

    pop3_server=
    pop3_username=
    pop3_password=

    ; to force the sender to always be the following email address, uncomment and
    ; populate with a valid email address.  this will only affect the "MAIL FROM"
    ; command, it won't modify the "From: " header of the message content

    force_sender=webmaster@domain.com

    ; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
    ; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

    ;hostname=
```

and the email function in my php.ini is like this:

```
[mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    SMTP = localhost
    smtp_port = 25

    ; For Win32 only.
    sendmail_from = admin@whilgeek.com

    ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
    sendmail_path =C:\usr\lib\sendmail.exe -t

    ; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
    ; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
    ; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
    ;mail.force_extra_parameters =
```

I use userCake1.4( [download form here](http://www.ahaugas.com/downloads.php) ) in my computer and it says sent email successfully. But I didn't receive the email sent to my gamil.

What't wrong?

Comment: First thing: check spam.

Comment: You can also enable the debug log and write the content here.

Comment: Does google know it should be a relay for "whilgeek.com"?

Comment: are you running a server that is connectected to the internet?
ie: is that mail server accessible from anywhere on the internet?
some of my colleagues were sitting with this problem for a month trying to send emails from a local server and they were breaking their heads over it, but you have to have a server running on your machine that is configured to be accessed from the internet. that means; if you run a website on that machine, I should be able to access that website from here in my country over the internet, you have to have your ISP provide you with this specific service

Comment: what happens if you change your port to 587?

Comment: @BugFinder so how to change it?

Comment: @Johni I think this is a good idea, how to do it?

Comment: @goldenparrot so how should I do?

Comment: @pyruva My computer is connected to the internet surely.

Comment: of course your machine is connected to the internet, but have you specifically asked your ISP to allow you to send email over the internet from your machine?

Comment: @user1614589 http://theedublogger.com/2010/05/27/missing-emails-have-you-checked-your-spam-folder/

Comment: @user1614589 justuncomment debug_logfile=debug.log and set the dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is reverse DNS lookup. When you send an email from a server, your server has to be connected to the internet and the reverse DNS lookup has to point back to your server.

For example, an address (A) record for mail.example.com points to the IP address 192.0.2.5. In pointer records of the reverse database, this IP address is stored as the domain name 5.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa pointing back to its designated host name mail.example.com.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup